# how to optimize away common subexpressions?

Tags: sqlite, case

```
select x+y as z,  
case  
    when "x"+"y"  < 0 then "Less Than Zero"  
    when "x"+"y"  > 0 then "Non Zero"  
    else "Zero"  
end  
from sometable;
```

Returns expected result, but the addition is done with each row of data multiple times.

I am trying to optimize the query as follows but not working..

```
select x+y as z,  
case  
    when "z" < 0 then "Less Than Zero"  
    when "z" > 0 then "Non Zero"  
    else "Zero"  
end  
from sometable;
```

Always returns "Less Than Zero".

What am I doing wrong on this query? How can I avoid adding `A` and `B` multiple times while the query is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Column aliases in the SELECT clause are not available in other expressions in the same SELECT clause. (What should happen with `SELECT x AS y, y AS x ...`?)

You can make such an alias available by moving it into a subquery:

```
SELECT z,
       CASE WHEN z < 0 THEN 'Less Than Zero'
            WHEN z > 0 THEN 'Non Zero'
            ELSE            'Zero'
       END
FROM (SELECT x + y AS z
      FROM sometable);
```

However, this only saves typing; it does not actually optimize away the duplicate computation:

```
sqlite> explain select z, z from (select x+y as z from sometable);
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     11    0                    00  Start at 11
1     OpenRead       1     2     0     2              00  root=2 iDb=0; sometable
2     Rewind         1     9     0                    00
3       Column         1     0     3                    00  r[3]=sometable.x
4       Column         1     1     4                    00  r[4]=sometable.y
5       Add            4     3     1                    00  r[1]=r[4]+r[3]
6       Add            4     3     2                    00  r[2]=r[4]+r[3]
7       ResultRow      1     2     0                    00  output=r[1..2]
8     Next           1     3     0                    01
9     Close          1     0     0                    00
10    Halt           0     0     0                    00
11    Transaction    0     0     1     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
12    TableLock      0     2     0     sometable      00  iDb=0 root=2 write=0
13    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```